# No realiza mi registro

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Tengo el siguiente codigo php para realizar un registro nuevo en MYSQL

El problema es que en mi maquina funciona muy bien pero paso todo el proyecto al servidor donde se almacenan los proyecto y no realiza el insert me devuelve al index pero al revisar la base de datos no se realizo el insert.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

$trailer = $_REQUEST['trailer'];
$planta  = $_REQUEST['planta'];
$fecha   = $_REQUEST['Fecpro'];

$llenar=  strlen($trailer) * strlen($planta) * strlen($fecha);

if($llenar >0){
    require("validate.php");
    mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO plan_embarque (trailer,plant_code,prog_date) VALUES ('$trailer','$planta','$fecha')") or die ("Error:No se ingresaron los datos:");
    mysqli_close($link);
         ?>
    <script>
    alert("Se ha registrado exitosamente");
    window.location.href='index.php';
    </script>
    <?php

}

else{
    ?>
    <script>
    alert("Faltan datos por llenar");
    window.location.href='index.php';
    </script>
    <?php
}
}
?>
```

Modifique mi archivo PHP donde se realiza el insert para que me muestre si lo inserta o no de igual manera agregue un archivo validate para validar la conexion anexo el codigo a continuacion

```
<?php

$link= mysqli_connect("localhost","jmcroot","0797") or die ("Error al conectar al servidor:".mysqli_connect_error());

mysqli_select_db($link,"control_rampas") or die ("Error al seleccionar bd:".mysqli_connect_error());

?>
```

Y al realizar el insert me muestra el mensaje "Error:No se ingresaron los datos:"

Pero no me muestra el error de conexion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: QUé sale en los logs de php?

Comment: Prueba cerrando la conexión al final del código con `mysqli_close( $link );`

Comment: sabes si se realiza la conexión de forma exitosa??

Comment: El autor menciona que de manera local le inserta los datos, pero al momento de alojarlo al servidor no se inserta.

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Son duendes magicos que hace que algo corra en php 8 y en php 5.6 no... que tal si comiensas a investigar por hay en algo que se llama log de errores de apache ???

Comment: tambien viendo el codigo estoy casi seguro que si haces `echo var_export($QueryInsert,true);` el resultado sera algo como `boolean true`

Comment: Cabe aclarar que no estoy usando hosting estoy usando un servidor local de igual manera agregue un gif del proceso que realiza mi proyecto y el codigo

Comment: Mi codigo ya esta cambiado a la conexion de mi servidor como USER"JMCROOT" y PASSWORD"0797" y de echo en el proyecto tengo otra funcion de UPDATE y esa si la realiza exitosamente la unica que no realiza el registro es la del MODAL que es INSERT de echo les comento que en mi equipo funciona bien

Comment: Pon un `var_dump($_REQUEST);` en tu código y dinos qué muestra. Confírmanos que has verificado que la tabla `plan_embarque` existe en tu entorno de servidor y que la conexión es exitosa. Dicho eso, tu código es demasiado ingenuo, controla todos los posibles errores.

Comment: estoy casi seguroque no deberias programar con `php-8` para despues subirlo a `php-5.6` y esperar que funcione...

Comment: Pues no es que yo quiera es con lo que dejaron el servidor el que estaba antes de mi y no puedo venir a cambiar todo por que afecta a los otros sistemas que se estan usando por eso no se ha hecho el update y es la primera ves que tengo el problema pero recalco solo falla con el insert tengo 3 consultas de update y esas si las hace perfectamente

Comment: Ya ejecute el var_dump($_REQUEST); en mi index y lo que recibo me muestra "array(0) { }" es lo que me muestra en el index y en la consola de chrome con desplegarla con F12 no me muestra ninguna alerta error al ejecutar el insert

Comment: Ya edite mi post agregue el nuevo codigo que use para el insert y al realizarlo solo me muestra error no se ingresaron los datos